# "excel stopped working" message on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

We faced serious problem with Excel 2003. A message "excel stopped working" is displayed and excel just restarts. We start it with compatibility option for Windows XP, and I turned off user account control but it does not help.

Reinstallation does not resolve the problem. User has administrative rights to the computer.  What can we do to fix this problem?

This problem is serious specially when You use ctrl-c ctrl-v sequence. Must we buy newer version of Office? Is that solution? Or Office 2007 has the same problem? What about Office 2010? Do Microsoft says anything about this **common** issue?

Comment: I have read that it is rather common and unsolved problem... http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeinstall/thread/b7c167e1-3394-42c6-b2fb-b3667f833888

Comment: well, it seems it is like there is no solution. Do You use newer version of MS Office? Is it working fine?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Microsoft Office Update (SP3) for Office 2010 Professional (October 2011), Excel 2010 does the same thing. It only seems to occur when editing and/or adding large formula content without frequently saving. Hopefully the Office wizards will realize the problem and provide a fix in future updates.